# Angular - allow user to click a button that generates a webpage server-side, and passes result to PDF converter

Tags: angular, pdf, server-side, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am using Angular 2 - I'm wanting the user to be able to click a button on a webpage that goes to the server and generates a separate Angular page and then for that webpage to be converted to PDF, and finally for the PDF to be returned to the user/browser.

I know Angular Universal can generate a webpage in parallel to a user/browser request and return it to the browser, but is it flexible enough to pass the result (generated webpage) off to a server-side process as opposed to returning the generated webpage back to the browser ?

If not, are there other alternatives such as [angularjs-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-server) or perhaps [angular.js-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular.js-server) ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular definitely is flexible enough.

The server-side rendered page is generated by a call to the [renderModuleFactory](https://angular.io/api/platform-server/renderModuleFactory). All you get back from that method (as soon as the promise is resolved) is the rendered page as one string which contains all the HMTL.

You can easily use that string to do further server-side processing before passing it back to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Moema - I've had a look at renderModuleFactory and am a little unclear - doesn't it (renderModuleFactory) already assume you have the rendered HTML (i.e. isn't the rendered HTML string passed to renderModuleFactory as the first parameter) - can you explain how it is used (inputs/outputs) - basically I want to give it an Angular template page and a data model - then for it to process (resolve all bindings with the Angular template page) and return a HTML string

Comment: No, renderModuleFactory needs a NgModuleFactory as argument. That is, to make short, a compiled Angular App. There a tons of blogs explaining how it works, see https://medium.com/@feloy/angular-v4-universal-demystified-f06a576d6ca2 to name just one arbitrary example